# Usar listas comprimidas en nested loop python

Tags: python, bucles, numpy

¿Es posible optimizar este bucle con listas comprimidas o de alguna otra forma?

```
index = np.zeros((o_h*o_w,np.prod(f_s)), np.int32)
idx_1 = np.array([i for j in range(0,k_h*i_w,i_w) for i in range(j,j+k_w)])
for i in range(o_h):
    for j in range(o_w):
        index[o_w*i+j,:] = idx_1 + j + i*o_w + i
```

Comment: Aunque es posible reducir los "for" anidados a una sola linea usando listas comprimidas, perderias en legibilidad. Yo lo dejaría como está.